# How can I interpolate JSX with an expression in a string?

Tags: reactjs

Looking to achieve the following:

```
<div className="total total-{obj.state}">
```

Obviously this compiles to:

```
<div class="total total-{obj.state}">
```

Is there an elegant way in JSX to evaluate the expression in the `{}` within a string?

Comment: If you're using Babel: ``<div className={ `total total-${obj.state}` }>``

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Try this (ES5):

```
<div className={'total total-' + obj.state}>...</div>
```

Or with ES6+

```
<div className={`total total-${obj.state}`}>...</div>
```

Remember that everything between `{` and `}` is just Javascript, so the expression is `'total total-' + obj.state` which is then set as the class of the DOM node.

Comment: use this package also for class name manipulation https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Comment: if you're using babel, you may as well start using string templating with the backticks `\``. So in this example you'd use: ``<div className={`total total-${obj.state}`}>``

Comment: Just because you *can* use string interpolation, doesn't mean you should -- it isn't faster, and its clarity is a matter of debate. Perl5 had string interpolation from the start, and it took years for it to become taboo as unclear.

Answer (score 86):

You could use a react expression and then the javascript [es6 string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Something like this:

```
<div someProp={`${SomeConstOrVariableOrExpression} simple text`}></div>
```